# Python code to compare dates within matching IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, date, filter, match

I have the following data in a table:

| ID | Order Date | Discharge Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1/2/2023 | 1/2/2023 |
| 001 |  | 2/27/2023 |
| 002 | 2/14/2023 | 2/15/2023 |
| 002 | 3/29/2023 | 4/1/2023 |
| 002 |  | 7/2/2023 |
| 003 |  | 4/1/2023 |
| 003 |  | 5/15/2023 |

I want to add a column that return a 'Yes' for any 'Discharge date' with 30 days of an 'Order date', and it can be any order date for a matching ID. It should look like this:

| ID | Order Date | Discharge Date | 30 Day Review |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1/2/2023 | 1/2/2023 | Yes |
| 001 |  | 2/27/2023 | No |
| 002 | 2/14/2023 | 2/15/2023 | Yes |
| 002 | 3/29/2023 | 4/1/2023 | Yes |
| 002 |  | 4/18/2023 | Yes |
| 003 |  | 4/1/2023 | No |
| 003 |  | 5/15/2023 | No |

I have tried:

```
df['30 day review'] = 'No'

for match_id in df['ID'].unique():
    rows = df[df['ID'] == match_id]
    if any(rows['Order Date'] <= rows rows['Discharge Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=30)):
        df.loc[df['ID'] == match_id, '30 day review'] = 'Yes'
```

But this gives me a 'Yes' for every row for a given match ID as a group and not comparing that row discharge date to all available order dates within that ID group. For ex, in my table above it would return a Yes for all in ID 001, instead a Yes in row 1 and a No in row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ffill`:

```
df['30 Day Review'] = (
 pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], dayfirst=False)
   .groupby(df['ID']).ffill()
   .rsub(pd.to_datetime(df['Discharge Date'], dayfirst=False))
   .le('30D')
)
```

*NB. this solution only works if the values are already sorted and `Discharge Date` is always posterior to previous rows' `Order Date` in a group. For a robust solution independent of the row order, see the second approach with `merge_asof`.*

Output:

```
   ID Order Date Discharge Date  30 Day Review
0   1   1/2/2023       1/2/2023           True
1   1        NaN      2/27/2023          False
2   2  2/14/2023      2/15/2023           True
3   2  3/29/2023       4/1/2023           True
4   2        NaN       7/2/2023          False
5   3        NaN       4/1/2023          False
6   3        NaN      5/15/2023          False
```

For `Yes`/`No`:

```
df['30 Day Review'] = np.where(
 pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], dayfirst=False)
   .groupby(df['ID']).ffill()
   .rsub(pd.to_datetime(df['Discharge Date'], dayfirst=False))
   .le('30D'),
    'Yes', 'No'
)
```

Output:

```
   ID Order Date Discharge Date 30 Day Review
0   1   1/2/2023       1/2/2023           Yes
1   1        NaN      2/27/2023            No
2   2  2/14/2023      2/15/2023           Yes
3   2  3/29/2023       4/1/2023           Yes
4   2        NaN       7/2/2023            No
5   3        NaN       4/1/2023            No
6   3        NaN      5/15/2023            No
```

##### using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
m = pd.merge_asof(
    df[['ID']].assign(discharge=pd.to_datetime(df['Discharge Date'], dayfirst=False))
              .reset_index().sort_values(by='discharge'),
    df[['ID']].assign(order=pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], dayfirst=False))
              .sort_values(by='order').dropna(subset='order'),
    by='ID', left_on='discharge', right_on='order',
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30D')
).set_index('index')['order'].notna().reindex(df.index)

df['30 Day Review'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
   ID Order Date Discharge Date 30 Day Review
0   1   1/2/2023       1/2/2023           Yes
1   1        NaN      2/27/2023            No
2   2  2/14/2023      2/15/2023           Yes
3   2  3/29/2023       4/1/2023           Yes
4   2        NaN      4/18/2023           Yes
5   3        NaN       4/1/2023            No
6   3        NaN      5/15/2023            No
```

Comment: I attempted the merge_asof() method, but got a TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'order' was passed

Comment: I was able to make the merge_asof code work by adding closed brackets [] around the dropna(subset=['order']). Not 100% why that was required, but happy to have it function.

Comment: @ChrisLinke yes this is a pandas version issue, older versions required the brackets, not the latest ones ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where()`, which allows you to return one value or another depending on a condition:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l1 = ["001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "003", "003"]
l2 = ["1/2/2023", None, "2/14/2023", "3/29/2023", None, None, None]
l3 = ["1/2/2023", "2/27/2023", "2/15/2023", "4/1/2023", "7/2/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/15/2023"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": l1, "Order Date": l2, "Discharge Date": l3})
df["Order Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Order Date"])
df["Discharge Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Discharge Date"])

# group by ID and forward fill all order dates, then fill any that are still "none" as 1/1/1900
# then if the difference between these and the discharge date (in days) is greater than 30
# return "No", else "Yes"
df["30-day review"] = np.where(
    (df["Discharge Date"] - df.groupby("ID")["Order Date"].ffill().fillna(
        pd.Timestamp(1900,1,1))).dt.days > 30,
    "No",  # if greater than 30 days difference
    "Yes")  # if less than or equal to 30 days difference

df
Out[]: 
#    ID Order Date Discharge Date 30-day review
#0  001 2023-01-02     2023-01-02           Yes
#1  001        NaT     2023-02-27            No
#2  002 2023-02-14     2023-02-15           Yes
#3  002 2023-03-29     2023-04-01           Yes
#4  002        NaT     2023-07-02            No
#5  003        NaT     2023-04-01            No
#6  003        NaT     2023-05-15            No
```

Comment: Another answer by @mozway is almost exactly the same, but slightly different syntax to calculate.

Comment: I actually think this approach is not robust, I added a better alternative which should always work.